# sed: remove all non-alphanumeric characters inside quotations only

Tags: regex, bash, sed, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

Say I have a string like this:

```
Output:   
I have some-non-alphanumeric % characters remain here, I "also, have_+ some & .here"
```

I want to **only** remove non-alphanumeric characters inside the quotations **except commas, periods, or spaces**:

```
Desired Output:    
I have some-non-alphanumeric % characters remain here, I "also, have some  .here"
```

I have tried the following `sed` command matching a string and deleting inside the quotes, but it deletes everything that is inside the quotes including the quotes:

```
sed '/characters/ s/\("[^"]*\)\([^a-zA-Z0-9\,\. ]\)\([^"]*"\)//g'
```

Any help is appreciated, preferably using `sed`, to get the desired output.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: sed is not the right tool for this. What about Perl? Did you wanna perl solution?

Comment: Well I am adding this piece of code to an existing script to which I will pass on to other users... #!/bin/bash is my shell, so I don't think perl is beneficial here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat your substitution multiple times to remove all non-alphanumeric characters. Doing such a loop in sed requires a label and use of the `b` and `t` commands:

```
sed '
# If the line contains /characters/, just to label repremove
/characters/ b repremove
# else, jump to end of script
b
# labels are introduced with colons
:repremove
# This s command says: find a quote mark and some stuff we do not want
# to remove, then some stuff we do want to remove, then the rest until
# a quote mark again. Replace it with the two things we did not want to
# remove
s/\("[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*\)[^"a-zA-Z0-9,. ][^"a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*\([^"]*"\)/\1\2/
# The t command repeats the loop until we have gotten everything
t repremove
'
```

(This will work even without the `[^"a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*`, but it'll be slower on lines that contain many non-alphanumeric characters in a row)

Though the other answer is right in that doing this in perl is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Sed is not the right tools for this. Here is the one through Perl.

```
perl -pe 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9,.\s"](?!(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)//g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'I have some-non-alphanumeric % characters remain here, I "also, have_+ some & .here"' | perl -pe 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9,.\s"](?!(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)//g'
I have some-non-alphanumeric % characters remain here, I "also, have some  .here"
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pV8tN5/1)